# How to have more cells in a single cell in datagrid - silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I am trying to create a table with as shown below,

[image]

Here is my Code:

```
 <my:DataGrid>
     <my:DataGrid.Columns>
         <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Class"/>
         <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Sec"/>
         <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Monday"/>
         <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Tuesday"/>
         <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Wednesday"/>
         <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Thursday"/>
         <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Friday"/>
      </my:DataGrid.Columns>
  </my:DataGrid>
```

How to include the columns 1 to 8 inside the column **Monday**
Can any help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go,

```
<UserControl xmlns:Controls1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"   
xmlns:Primitives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly= System.Windows.Controls.Data"
xmlns:vsm="clr-namespace:System.Windows;assembly=System.Windows"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Controls1:DataGrid>
             <Controls1:DataGrid.Columns>
                <Controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Monday" Width="2.5*">
                    <Controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader" BasedOn="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Primitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                        <Grid Name="Root">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SortStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unsorted" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="SortAscending"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="SortDescending"/>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundRectangle" Stretch="Fill" Fill="Yellow" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                                            <Rectangle x:Name="BackgroundGradient" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" >
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB93A42" Offset="0" />
                                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF48030A" Offset="1" />
                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                                            </Rectangle>

                                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Text="Monday" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" Grid.Row="0"/>
                                                <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Height="1" />
                                                <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="1"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="2"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="3"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="4"/>
                                                    <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="5"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Rectangle Name="VerticalSeparator" Grid.Column="1" Width="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="{TemplateBinding SeparatorBrush}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding SeparatorVisibility}" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <Controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding 1}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding 2}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding 3}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding 3}"/>
                                <TextBlock Margin="2" Grid.Column="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding 4}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </Controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </Controls1:DataGrid.Columns>
        </Controls1:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I am getting an error in `DataTemplate` as `Invalid Binding path;Character 1 in 1` What does it it mean? @sajeetharan

Comment: @Dhinesh Just double check, copy and paste it ! It is a working code

Comment: Is there any reference need to be added manually? It says the `datagrid`is not present in the namespace

Comment: Yes you need to put the namespaces! ok i have added the namespaces too, check them

Comment: I manually added `System.Windows.controls.data` extension to reference folder and it worked but during runtime I am getting an error on `BasedOn="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}"` in the `Style`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put another datagrid inside one of your cells.
The second datagrid will contains 2 rows: first row for Monday and second row should have 8 columns.